# Storing a string in a matrix

Tags: python, string

Suppose i have a string `a='SKDKFJKFLKG'` and I want to store it in a matrix with each letter as an element of the matrix.I am using the following code to store it in a matrix:

```
def chunks(l, n):

    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
pprint.pprint(list(chunks(a, 1)))
```

Output:

```
['S', 'K', 'D', 'K', 'F', 'J', 'K', 'F', 'L', 'K', 'G']
```

What should i do if i want only 4 characters in each row of the matrix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: So, still didn't figure out what number to pass as `n`?

Comment: Well, if all else fails, try at random and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, I'll bite: Just call it using `pprint.pprint(list(chunks(a, 4)))`